# Override indexOf in LinkedList to check for identity, not equality

Tags: java, list, indexof

I have a `List` (actually a `LinkedList`) and I add Items to it which implement the `equals`-method.

The problem is that I add items that are equal, but not identical (like two initialized objects). Now, when I want to get the index of the item I added second, I get, of course, the element of the first item, because `indexOf` searches for equality and not identity.

I tried to create my own subclass of `LinkedList` and overwrite the `indexOf`-method, but this is not possible, because I don't have access to neither the subclass `Node` nor the Node-Element `first`.

Here is an example:

```
public class ExampleObject {

  int number;

  public ExampleObject(){
    number = 0;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
    ExampleObject other = (ExampleObject) obj;
    if (number != other.number) return false;
    return true;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<ExampleObject> list = new LinkedList<ExampleObject>();

    ExampleObject one = new ExampleObject();
    ExampleObject two = new ExampleObject();

    list.add(one);
    list.add(two);

    System.out.println(list.indexOf(one)); // '0' as expected
    System.out.println(list.indexOf(two)); // '0', but I want to get '1'

  }
}
```

My intention: I need a list of objects, where I want to store initialized objects and edit them later.

Comment: Then why do you override `equals` method at all? Use `Object#equals`, it will do identity matching for you.

Comment: Dont override `equals()`. And there you have it.

Comment: How will you distinguish between two initialized objects?

Comment: By their reference. See equals implementation in Object.

Comment: `one.equals(one) --> true and one.equals(anything else) --> false`

Comment: `return (this == obj);` thts how equals of Object works.

Comment: @Rohit I need an `equals`-method at a different point, that checks for equality and not only for identity. I could make an `equals2` method, that checks for it, but that looks like messy code for me, to have two different `equals`-methods with different behavior.

Comment: @Karna I keep track of the references at multiple positions in my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do the iteration yourself, `indexOf` is just a helper method:

```
static int indexOfById(List<?> list, Object searchedObject) {
  int i = 0;
  for (Object o : list) {
    if (o == searchedObject) return i;
    i++;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: I feel stupid for not thinking of this easy solution. I was worried about time-intense `get`-accesses, but this simply avoids it.

Comment: Does your use case really make `LinkedList` inevitable?

Comment: I definitely must allow double entries. In addition the size must be flexible because adding and removing objects happens often. On the other hand I do not need to access elements by it's index very often... do you have a better idea for a data structure in your mind?

Comment: Sure, `ArrayList` fulfills all your requirements, and is generally the number one choice of a `List` implementation in Java. Much more memory-efficient than `LinkedList`, O(1) random access (and with a very small constant factor, basically as fast as array access), faster iteration, etc. We choose `LinkedList` only if you have a very specific requirement at which `ArrayList` is not good: a lot of insertions/deletions in the middle of the list.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions to this problem.

1) The correct solution: If you need identity comparison, then you should not override the `equals` method. You told us that you must override it, as you need it in another place. That indicates a design problem in your software, and you really should solve this.

2) Have a look at the class `sun.awt.util.IdentityLinkedList`. This is nearly a "normal" `LinkedList` with the identity behavior for the `indexOf` method. If you do not want to rely on a class in a sun sub-package, you can copy the code into a class that resides in your packages.

3) You could follow a procedural solution with iterating the list yourself:

```
public static <E> int indexOf(List<E> list, E searchItem) {
    int index = 0;
    for (E item : list) {
        if (item == searchItem)
            return index;
        index += 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

4) Write a wrapper for your objects.

```
public class IdentityWrapper {
    public Object item;
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        IdentityWrapper other = (IdentityWrapper) obj;
        return item == other.item;
    }
}
```

Then use this wrapper in your list: `LinkedList<IdentityWrapper>`. Note, that I provided a public item field in the wrapper. Normally, I would do it with a constructor and a private field only.

Comment: Also nice solutions, I never knew about `IdentityLinkedList`. Your opinion about 1) worries me... On the one hand I have direct references inside my program but on the other hand I have to read data from a text-file, create new objects from that data and either match it with existing objects in my list or create a new entry... is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I fear, that this description of requirements is not clear enough to get to the design problem you have. What exactly do you mean with "direct references inside my program"? The file reading requirement seems to use the "normal" equals method ...

Comment: I create a GUI. I have a core data structure that contains multiple objects (in `LinkedLists`, as you could guess). The GUI consists of graphical elements that have references to single elements from the core data structure to keep track of changes and to modify those single objects. The "finished" data structure will be sent to a different program (consider it a black box) for analysis and the output of that program is in a file. More clear?

Comment: Hmm ... Where do you need the identity comparison, and where do you need the equality comparison? Something else: I never have any of the collections (from Java's Collection API) being propagated to users of my classes (i.e. I never have a getter returning a collection). Collections are meant to implement 1:n relationships. So maybe you just need a controlling class whose methods implement the behavior you need, and internally manages the objects in whatever data structure you think of (which could be a LinkedList, for example).

Comment: I suspect we drift apart in what we are talking about... I'm also concerned that it would be too time-consuming for both you and me if I try to explain it in further detail. Thanks anyway, your statements helped me to rethink about substantial parts of my design. Daher danke nochmal ;-)